# How to remove the sort indicator in GtkTreeViewColumn keeping the column sortable?

Tags: gtk

I know it's a bug that is considered not an issue but when you have many columns that you still want them sortable, all displayed without the need to scroll right and left and the sort arrow indicator is not so important. What are available workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it can be done by **not** applying `set_sort_column_id` to the **treeview column**. We must do it programatically through using `set_clickable` method to the the column that you don't want an arrow to be displayed in its header, then using `signal_connect` to the `clicked` signal and bind it to a **function** which will use `get_sort_column_id` of the **model** to get the current sort order whether `GTK_SORT_ASCENDING` or `GTK_SORT_DESCENDING` then apply the **reverse** sort order using `set_sort_column_id` on the **model**.